# React Native setState does not refresh render

Tags: react-native

I try to get which is not active (in term of NativeBase.io - https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#button-def-headref, which simply means that it has no background color) and after I click it, it becomes active (it has a background color).

I define button like this:

```
  <Button active={this.state.selected} onPress={() => this.select()} first>
      <Text>Puppies</Text>
  </Button>
```

`selected` variable in my state is by default false. When I run the application, it works correctly.

The `select()` method is implemented:

```
  select() {
    this.setState({ selected: true })
  }
```

I expect that after I click on the button, it should change its background but it isn't. I check the value of this.state.selected and it changes appropriately. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Be sure to have a default value for `this.state.selected`

Comment: I set a default value in my constructor.

Comment: Please verify that there will be visible change when you hard code the `active` to true and false.

Comment: Yes, there is visible change, when I change value in constructor. That is why I think that the problem is with reloading.

Comment: I suggest you replace `active` with `transparent` and test

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score -1):

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: false
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    const { selected } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      selected: !selected,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;

    return (
      <Button active={selected} onPress={this.handlePress} first>
        <Text>Puppies</Text>
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I completely don't get what is wrong. I try to implement your simple example, which look perfectly fine and it doesn't work. I added console log with the selected value, and after I click the button, I see: `selected:  false`, `selected:  true`, `selected:  false` and go on... but the color doesn't change. Do you think that the problem can be related to native base?

Comment: If this doesn't work, nativebase is the problem then. Not react-native.